# Catkin Unable to Find gmock - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cmake, ros, googletest, googlemock, catkin

I recently was following a tutorial to install a package and installed googletest from source without realising I already had the package locally.

I am now trying to do a clean build on a ROS package that previously built however I now fail to build anything that contains gmock.

I have tried purging gmock and googletest from my system but it still fails.

I added these lines to my cmake file to help debug:

```
message(**********************************)
message(${GTEST_LIBRARIES})
message(${GMOCK_LIBRARIES})
message(**********************************)
```

And the results I get are the following:

```
**********************************
/usr/lib/libgtest.a
CMake Error at magic_carpet_simulation/magic_carpet_simulation/CMakeLists.txt:36 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments


**********************************
```

This shows that I can find gtest but not gmock. I checked /usr/lib and found that there is definately a gmock package installed:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2451054 Oct 18 09:43 libgmock.a
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2455202 Oct 18 09:43 libgmock_main.a
```

Here is my cmake file slightly edited to maintain privacy but structure is the same:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(example)

find_package(cmake_utils 0.3.0 REQUIRED)
include(TopLevel)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        subscriber_helpers
        )

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS
        include
        test/include
    LIBRARIES
        lookup_table_1d
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
        nav_msgs
        roscpp
        subscriber_helpers
        )

message(**********************************)
message(${GTEST_LIBRARIES})
message(${GMOCK_LIBRARIES})
message(**********************************)

add_library(lookup_table_1d
        src/lookup_table_1d.cpp)
target_include_directories(lookup_table_1d PRIVATE
        include
        ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(lookup_table_1d ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

# Library of utilities required by all integration tests
add_library(simulation_integration_test_common
        test/integration/example.cpp)
target_include_directories(simulation_integration_test_common PRIVATE
        test/include
        ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${GMOCK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(simulation_integration_test_common ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(DIRECTORY launch/
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.launch" PATTERN "*.yaml")

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")

install(
    TARGETS
        lookup_table_1d
    PERMISSIONS
        OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE
        GROUP_READ GROUP_WRITE GROUP_EXECUTE
        WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING AND BUILD_TESTS)
    ## Unit Tests...
    ## Pipeline tests...
endif()
```

I am not too sure where to go from here?

Comment: It is difficult to suggest solutions without knowing how you are making CMake aware of the `GTEST` and `GMOCK` libraries. Can you please add your CMake file to the question post?

Comment: I have added a segment of the cmake, let me know if it is enough to help.

Comment: Ok, do you have any `GTEST` or `GMOCK` related output when you run CMake? Perhaps, "Found GTest ..." or "Found GMock ..." ? If so, it would be helpful to add this to your post as well. As always with CMake, it is often helpful to delete your CMakeCache.txt file (clear the CMake cache) and start with a fresh run of CMake to get rid of any stale variables from previous configurations.

Comment: Also, this is good to remember, in your catkin workspace, it may help to delete the devel/ build/ folders when problems like this occurs.

Comment: So I have been doing a clean build, looking at the build info we find Gtest and this is located in the catkin variable `catkin_LIBRARIES` which shows `/usr/lib/libgtest.a` however does not specify `libgmock.a` which is definitely in that dir.